# unable to use animated collapse div js and bootstrap 2.3.2 dropdown js at same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a header with a dropdown menu, it uses bootstrap-dropdown.js, bootstrap.js, bootstrap.min.js and jquery-1.10.2.min.js.
In the same page, I have a animated collapsible div, which uses jquery.js and

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery().ready(function(){  

    // applying the settings

    jQuery('#theMenu1').Accordion({

        active: 'h6.selected',
        header: 'h6.head',
        alwaysOpen: false,
        animated: true,
        showSpeed: 400,
        hideSpeed: 800

    });

}); 
</script>
```

The header drop-down doesn't works when I have jquery.js, in my page.

And if I remove jquery.js, the animated div doesn't works.

Kindly suggest what can be done.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem and solve it to delete bootstrap.js just use bootstrap.min.js. Actually bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js are same file when compare with content, min.js files always contains removed whitespace characters.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I am not sure but there is an conflict when add both bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap.js

**EDIT:** Give the solution with current latest bootstrap version, it should be common problem for bootstrap and solve the previous versions too.

**EDIT :** [Source](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-overview)

> Using the compiled JavaScript
>
> Both bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js contain all plugins in a single
>   file. **Include only one**.